# Display a Toast message if a checkbox is true on parent record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, notification, toast

I'm trying to display a toast notification whenever a quote is visited and its related opportunity lookup has a boolean field with a value of true (Ordered_Custom__c = true).  This aura component is working, but it's also displaying some strange functionality.  For example - Sometimes if I update Ordered_Custom__c to true on the opportunity the toast message will pop up, even though I've only added this component to the Quote lightning record page.  Does anyone know why this would be happening and if there's a way around it?  It seems to happen only after I've been navigating back and forth between a quote and its opportunity record.

Here's the cmp file:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes, force:hasRecordId, force:hasSObjectName" access="global" >

<lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>

<aura:attribute name="record" type="Map" default="{}"/>

<force:recordData 
recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
layoutType="FULL" 
targetFields="{!v.record}"
fields="SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Ordered_Custom__c"
recordUpdated="{!c.optionalShowToast}" />

</aura:component>
```

And here's the js controller:

```
({
optionalShowToast: function(component, event, helper){
    var quote = component.get("v.record");

    if(quote.SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Ordered_Custom__c == true){         
    component.find('notifLib').showToast({
        title: "Alert",
        message: "This quote has contracted pricing.",
        variant: "warning",
        mode: "sticky"
    });
}
}
```

})

Comment: Hi there, when you say navigating back and forth between the pages, are they both open still? Or is the quote record paged closed?

Comment: @callum here's the steps I take to get the toast message to pop up on the opportunity.  1) Set the checkbox to false on the opp.  2) Navigate to the quote within the same tab via a lookup field on the opp.  3) Navigate back to the opp in the same tab via a lookup field on the quote.  4) Set the checkbox to true on the opp.